# Error while opening search result types in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a Search Service application and i want to customize how my search results look. I have a customized display template as well. But when i open my Search Result types i get an error saying Something went wrong.And also none of the managed properties can be seen.
I looked for logs and the log says,
 **

- **Error executing stored procedure proc_MSS_GetResultItemTypes:
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The target principal
  name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.**
- **Error retrieving ResultItemTypes from the admin db: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.**
- **QueryPipelineDatabase:HandleSqlException - Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The target principal name is incorrect.  Cannot generate SSPI context.**

Can somebody please help me with this.

Comment: is your data source for search SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and the solution was my Default content access account's password in my Search Service Application had expired and we updated the password and it started working